# PHP Choose Array Item Percentage of The Time?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out a way to have a particular array item chosen a certain percentage of the time. So lets say:

```
$testArray = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5');
```

Now how would I go about having item1 chosen lets say 40% of the time. I know this is probably really easy but I can't seem to wrap my head around it today.

Answer (score 3):

With these percentages:

```
$chances = array(40,15,15,15,15);
```

Choose a random number between 1 and 100:

```
$rand = rand(1,100);
```

And select the according array item:

```
| item1              | item2  | item3  | item4  | item5  |
0                   40       55       70       85       100
```

```php
$ref = 0;
foreach ($chances as $key => $chance) {
    $ref += $chance;
    if ($rand <= $ref) {
        return $testArray[$key];
    }
}
```

**Possible improvement for a more general solution:**

- use `array_sum()` instead `100`
- assure that `$chances` has the same keys as the input array (i.e. with `array_keys` and `array_combine`)